# Migration from Windows to Linux hosting

Tags: php, web-hosting, linux, windows, migration

I'm looking forward installing a CMS for my sites - most likely Joomla - but apparently Windows hosting doesn't support it. **I was wondering what kind of changes I'd have to perform if I changed to Linux.** It took me a long time to finally have the PHP form working and I wouldn't want to go all through that again. Aside from that and a Wordpress widget, I don't think I use any other code that would need tweaking.

Comment: Pardon me as i cannot comment yet. This maybe a better question for http://serverfault.com as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a standard linux (apache webserver) hosting environment it should be easier to get a php form and wordpress widget to work without tweaks. Without knowing what you did to make them work, it's difficult to answer your question. I've used hosts such as readyhosting.com that allow php to run on windows servers, but many hosts have better support for php based applications on linux hosting.

Overall, moving to a linux host for easy management of a cms system should outweigh whatever work it took to get your other items working on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows supports Joomla because it supports PHP. However you may not find many hosts that have it as a pre-installed option. However a Google search turns up one that gives you instructions on how to install it on their hosting and so there may be others.

Answer (score 0):

As the person above said, installing Joomla is possible in windows hosting account where php is supported. But you have to manually install it(download from Joomla, upload to site, config etc). Could be a pain.

Comment: I removed a link to a windows web host that supports PHP as it added nothing to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows hosting is not just for ASP.NET. You can use Apache, PHP, and MySQL very easily here.

This is the platform that the majority of developers use for PHP and MySQL (for example: mysql.com reported that 6-7 out of 10 downloads where for Windows builds, in 2009). And there is no reason why you can't get a Windows VPS, uninstall any control panel that comes with it or disable IIS, and use Apache + PHP + MySQL.

You could also use an all-in-one wamp package that will install this software for you.

There are free packages such as [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) and WampServer.

There are also commercial packages such as [Wamp Developer](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper), which installs Joomla for you automatically.